# MIRC scripting: how to save answer from bot

Tags: scripting, mirc

I have no privilegies to see database of stored users on some channel, but on channel is active bot. There is a command with parameters and bot answers with list of Users according to parameters.

Is there any possibilities to save answer from bot into variable or file for later use (remote scripting in MIRC)?

Comment: I'm sorry, this was the vaguest question i ever witness, Please edit your question and write it more clear so we could understand.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good. On some channel on mibbit is active boot. When normal user type command for listing some users boot answer with that list on channel (User1 User2 User3 ...). My question is: when in MIRC i make boot and in Remote section type same command for listing users, is there possibility to save answer User1 User2 User3 into variable for late ruse in script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like thatk

```
on BOT_NICK!*:text:*:#CHANNEL:write text.txt $1-
```

or you can find more helpful think on /help